# How to secure information in Android

Tags: java, android, security

How can I keep secure data from crackers in an android application? I need to use some secret keys (as the application will work through a web service) so I need to know where it would be recommended to keep this secret information and how?

Comment: Are you asking where to store passwords for a web service?

Comment: API keys and tokens... which are pretty much "passwords" like

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SharedPreferences` which is not stored in an accessible file/folder. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for information on SharedPreferences and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences) for how to use it. This is an example:

```
// Get settings
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
// Get editor to be able to put settings
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit()
// Put information with specified key
editor.putString("example_key", "example value");
// Commit changes
editor.commit();
// Gets value from setting with the specified key
String exampleString = settings.getString("example_key", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in a `Preferences` object and encrypt them with a hard-coded key, save them to the app's data folder and encrypt the whole file with a hard-coded key, or save them in a web location (which is probably the safest way to do it). You could also substitute a user-provided password for a hard-coded key, but that may be a nuisance depending on what the app does. If you're asking for a place that Android provides specifically for storing sensitive info, I don't believe any exists.