# Android - which is the best way to store some commonly used information of login user?

Tags: android

In my application i am using ksoap2 library to validate the username and password in android. now i want to know , which is the best and secure way to store commonly use information, so that i can fetch that information in any other screen whithout  requesting my webserver using ksoap.

I am from the web background, so i know that in web we store the user information in session or cookies. Session is stroed on the server and cookie is stored on the local machine.

I also read about cookies in android but i dont know how it works and where it is saved.

please let me know how can i do this? If you know any tutorial that can help me to learn this thing then please post it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use SharedPreferences ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreference for storing information, in the form of key value pairs.

```
private SharedPreferences myUserPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor myUserEdit;
 myUserPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("name of shared preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myUserEdit =  myUserPrefs.edit();
```

to save some info in SharedPreference:

```
myuserEdit.putString("key", "value");
myUserEdit.commit();
```

To fetch some value:

```
String=myUserPrefs.getString("key", "default value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code：

```
save:
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", yournamestored);
editor.commit();

get:
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);    
String ret = settings.getString("username", "defaultname");
```

cookies string and others so.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Prefrence is the best for your short data storage and sharing problem..But if you need you can use SQLlite dbase also..For more storage options in android, have a look on following

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and Session are not work in android.You have to use Shared Preferences or Static variable for your requirement.

If you validate the user every time when the application starts then its better to use static 
variable or

if you validate the user only once when application installed then its better to use Shared preference

Comment: may you please elaborate your 3rd line about shared preference.

Comment: Suppose some applications validate the user only once not validate every time while they start app.If your requirement is that see below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences