# SharedPreferences return only default value

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

So instead of creating a database, I'm storing the data using `SharedPreference`.

My code is below:

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("favid"+id, 1);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select as favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now I want to retrieve that data so I have used below code in **other activity**:

```
   strFav = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(strFav.size()>0)
        strFav.clear();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
    for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
        int favid = prefs.getInt("favid"+i, -1);
        if (favid != -1) 
        {
          strFav.add(i);
        }
    }
```

At time of data retrieve, I'm getting all value is `-1`.

Can any body help me why this is happening? I have committed many entries as 1, but I'm still getting `-1` result for all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) about `getPrefernces` method:

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are **private to this activity**.

So, if you want to share preferences between activities you should use [`getSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with specified name.

Comment: but jin i have also used "MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE" but that way it's not done :(

Comment: If you will use this preferences in your **app** only - you can use MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 1):

Do you use shared preferences in two different activieties of **one** app ?

Also try to specify preferences name, or use some Manager to handle all preferences, all this explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences)

Comment: thanks a lot dilix by  doing                                         SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("abc", 0);                       the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.putInt("favid"+id, 1);
```

what's about id is equals to 0? 
here you are reading starting from 1

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
```

Comment: are you sure editor.putInt("favid"+id, 1); the id vaules is != 0 when you perform the put?

Comment: it does not make sense to me.