# Android - NullPointerException when SharedPreferences are not initialized

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, initialization, sharedpreferences

I have some settings need to be retrieved on application start. I designed my settings page first, saved settings, and then added setting-retrieval code in main activity. The application worked fine.

But if I cleared data or did a fresh install, it results a NullPointerException, and I believe it's because the `shared_prefs/settings.xml` does not exist at all.

```java
SharedPreferences mSettings;
private String mUsername;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSettings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    mUsername = mSettings.getString("username", null);

    // this results a NullPointerException
    // but it'll be fine the next time app starts with the fix below
    //
    // Toast.makeText(this, mUsername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    // fix: manually initializing prefs
    if(mUsername == null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
        editor.putString("username", "Android");
        editor.commit();
        mUsername = "Android";
    }
}
```

The fix solves the problem. However, I haven't seen people doing pref initialization the way I did.

So I'm wondering if this is the correct way of initializing preferecnes?

Comment: Look at this [post][1] 
Check the code an try it again. Hope this helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "Android" as default value?

```
mUsername = mSettings.getString("username", "Android");
```

Comment: The username "Android" is unknown on app starts, it should not appear in the activity at all. Instead, it should be retrieved from SharedPreferences (shared_prefs/settings.xml).

Comment: Ofcourse after a fresh install you don't have preferences at all and because of it all retriving methods have default values - you have NPE because you return null as your default value. If you have to start settings activity first - you can start it if value is null. It's a common way to return some default values on the first start of the app. Preferences are used to save states between different starts of the app.