# Send a series of predefined sms messages at set intervals

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, alarm, android-pendingintent

I'm working on my first app and my aim is to send a series of predefined sms starting at the date and time set by user and then at set times relative to first (ie. first sms sent, 2nd sms sent at +3min, 3rd sms sent at +7min etc).  I've managed to do this by setting all alarms at once with different pendingintent request codes and having multiple broadcast receivers for each message but that doesn't seem efficient.  Is it possible to reuse the same request code (to make cancelling a series possible) and set an alarm after each broadcast is received, from the same receiver?  Code below, any suggestions welcome.

Main Activity

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Receiver1.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, number);

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Receiver2.class);
            intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, message2);
            intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_NUMBER, number);

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

            PendingIntent sender2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    MainActivity.this, 2, intent2, 0);

            // Set alarm for this time
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);

            // Schedule alarm
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

            AlarmManager am2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cal.getTimeInMillis() + 30 * 1000, sender2);
```

Receiver 1

```
public class Receiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER);

    sendSMS(number, message);
};

// ---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
};
}
```

Receiver 2

```
public class Receiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER);

    sendSMS(number, message);
};

// ---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
};
}
```

Comment: don't forget to help a brother out with a checkmark and/or upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store "state" in a file, in shared prefs or in a sqlite database.  Then you just need to do a bundle of work when your app wakes up and you can get down to one alarm and broadcast receiver.

I have a simple SharedPreferences example here:

[Android Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences/5734742#5734742)

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I will have a go at setting up an sqlite database for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                                   for (int count = 1; count <= total_sms; count++) {
                                    Log.i("----------------ppp------------",
                                            "-----working-----------" + count);
                                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number1, null,
                                            "Hai this is to test duration", null, null);
                                    Log.i("SMS_COUNT", "Number of sms send---" +count);
                                    Thread.sleep(1000 * (Integer.parseInt(delay)));

                                }

                                 } catch (Exception e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

        }
    }
    );
    t.start();
```