# How to save an Integer's value after the app closes?

Tags: java, android

I have an Integer on screen set to 100. When I click a button, that value goes down by one (99). However, when I restart the app, how can I get the same value as before which is 99, without it resetting to 100?

Comment: Using `SharedPreferences` for this would be the way to go

Comment: @itay lael Save the sharedPreferences in `onDestroy` and get the value in `onCreate`...

Comment: @TGMCians: In such cases, you should not be recommending using the `onDestroy()`. There are times when it is never called. Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to achieve what you want. Set the `count`, while exiting the app and when re-opening it, fetch it from there.

For example on how to go about using it, check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences).

Comment: Thanks!!
Helped me a lot!!
Just another little question,where im writing this?
onCreate or onPuse?

Comment: @itaylael : store in  `onPause` and get it back in `onCreate`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

In the `onPause()`, use this code to save the counter's value to a SharedPreference file

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt(KEY_NAME, THE_INTEGER_VALUE);
// Replace `putInt` with `putString` if your value is a String and not an Integer.
editor.commit();
```

1. Replace the `PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME` used above to choose the XML file that will be created to store the value in.
2. `KEY_NAME` used above is the KEY that will be used to access (for saving and reading from the SharedPreference file named in point 1.) It is part of the *Key-Value* pair used in SharedPreferences.
3. `THE_INTEGER_VALUE` is the actual value.

And in the `onResume()`, you can retreive the value back and display it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int counter = sharedPrefs.getInt(KEY_NAME, 0);
// Replace the `int counter` with `String counter` if your value is a String and not an Integer.
// Also, replace the `getInt` with `getString`
```

You can use the `int counter` later to display in a `TextView` perhaps.

Comment: Dude i have one more question that i didnt understend....if i put in the SharedPreferences String value how i get my count value from it?
and the String value Should be something special or just write in it something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SharedPreferences` in this way: **saving the value and then get it again**

```
private final String NUMBER = "Number";
private final String PROFILE = "Profile";

SharedPreferences a = FirstActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("a", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorProfiles = a.edit();
prefsEditorProfiles.putInt(Profile, 1);
prefsEditorProfiles.putInt(Number, 1);
prefsEditorProfiles.commit();
```

Then restore `SharedPreferences` in other `Activity`:

```
SharedPreferences a = SecondActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("a", MODE_PRIVATE);
int ab = a.getInt(Number, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use share preference as the [doc example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) changes to read/write int value:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       int lastIndex = settings.getInt("yournumbername", 100);
       setLastIndex(lastIndex);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("yournumbername", mlastIndex);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```