# Use sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wrote a code snippet that change the background color of the `LinearLayout` by selecting some `RadioButton`s , the main color of the layout is white , **but I want to keep one of these `RadioButton`s(their color) for always when it is checked** , but usually after closing the APP it turns to the main color. how can I use shared preference for this?

My .java file:`

```
public class Setting extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);

        final LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
        final RadioButton radio_red = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);
        final RadioButton radio_yellow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_yellow);

        radio_red.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        radio_yellow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Show us how you've tried to use shared preferences so far. The [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) is very clear on usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice example here:

[Android Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences/5734742#5734742)

You're just going to write a preference and read a preference.  Easy Peasy.