# Cannot resolve method 'getString' error: SharedPreferences helper class

Tags: android

I want to access a single shared preference file from multiple activities. I came across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences) which has a well explained answer suggesting to create a helper class for this purpose. And so I followed.. Here's my code:-

```
1  //helper class
2  public class AppUserInfo {
3  public static final String KEY_PREF_USERNAME = "username";
3  public static final String APP_USER_INFO =
4  AppUserInfo.class.getSimpleName();
5  private SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;
6  private SharedPreferences.Editor _prefEditor;
7
8  public AppUserInfo(Context context) {
9  this._sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_USER_INFO,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
10 this._prefEditor = _sharedPrefs.edit();
11 }
12
13 public String getUsername() {
14   return _prefEditor.getString(KEY_PREF_USERNAME, "");
15 }
16
17}
```

However,  while defining the `getUsername()` method, the IDE (Android Studio) points out the error below:-

> Cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

(Also tried to achieve a solution without the helper class. And the result..)

I would get the same error when, after having created the `user_info` shared preference file in **Activity A** and storing the key-value pair `{username : username@example.com}` in it, I was trying to do this in **Activity B**:-

```
SharedPreferences _userInfo = getSharedPreferences("user_info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor _prefEditor = _userInfo.edit();

String username = _prefEditor.getString("username","");
```

How do I resolve this error?
I'm also open to different approaches if any.

Comment: You can't get a String out of the `Editor` - use the `_sharedPrefs` instead.

Comment: @Darwind Oh damn me! Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hehe, no problem - sometimes it's the little things that gets you confused :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences.Editor` doesn't contains getter methods. It has methods that changes your preferences like - `putString(), remove()`, etc.
If you want to get the values corresponding to a key in your preferences file use -

```
 public String getUsername() {
   return this._sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_PREF_USERNAME, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things

```
private SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor _prefEditor;
```

Here, `_sharedPrefs` is going to be the object you **read** from, and `_prefEditor` is going to be the object you **write** to.

Your methods should read

```
public String getUsername() {

    // the read object
    return _sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_PREF_USERNAME, "");
}

public void setUsername(String s) {

    // the write object
    _prefEditor.putString(KEY_PREF_USERNAME, s);
    _prefEditor.commit()
}
```

When editing values in the editor object, be sure to call `commit` on it afterwards to push those changes back into the readable object.