# Alternatives to deal with many SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-resources

I'm developing an Android app which uses a high amout of SharedPreferences. I have several SharedPreferences files and I'm making up to 77 calls to these files throughout my app. Sometimes I'm using :

`static final String FileName= "SharedPreferencesFile";`

at the beginning of my activities and then :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

whenever I need to use them. Some other times I'm just refering to the files directly as in:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferencesFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I'm trying to organize things now so I would like to know about different alternatives to do it. My questions are:

1. Should I define a single "SharedPreferencesFile" for all the variables in my app or using multiple files as I'm doing now is ok?
2. Should I define all these `String FileName= "SharedPreferencesFile"` in the `strings.xml` from my app resources folder instead of putting them at the beginning of my activities and the just use them as `SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(R.string.SharedPreferencesFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
3. Should I create a helper class that handles all shared preferences calls for every activity as suggested in [Android Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences)

Comment: well why would you reference a shared preference with a static variable key then not in other places? keep it consistent and use the static key. Other than that is all preference

Comment: One point to note SharedPreferences will not work reliably across processes (MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is now deprecated as well) - if you're only using one process then you are fine.  Personally I always use a helper library I created that uses a content provider (which is process safe) to access my shared preferences, that way if later I decide to add a Service (or something similar) that runs in it's own process and need to access preferences then I'm covered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I define a single "SharedPreferencesFile" for all the variables
>   in my app or using multiple files as I'm doing now is ok?

If you can categorize them in a logical fashion do it. Dont just do it for the sake of having them split over multiple files in a random fashion. It will lead to a lot of confusion later

> Should I define all these String FileName= "SharedPreferencesFile" in
>   the strings.xml from my app resources folder instead of putting them
>   at the beginning of my activities and the just use them as
>   SharedPreferences settings =
>   getSharedPreferences(R.string.SharedPreferencesFile,
>   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

It is always good to have string resources extracted to `strings.xml`. Be careful if you are adding translations and make sure you don't translate the names. Mark them as `notranslate` string resources.

> Should I create a helper class that handles all shared preferences
>   calls for every activity as suggested in Android Shared Preferences

There are already several available. Here is one that I created to simplify the use of `SharedPreferences`. It is open source and can be used simply by adding a gradle dependency - [Android-SharedPreferences-Helper](https://github.com/viralypatel/Android-SharedPreferences-Helper)

Comment: @ AndroidMechanic what do you mean by "If you can categorize them in a logical fashion do it" having one file or many?

Comment: if you can logically group them into categories go for multiple files. otherwise you will end up having a lot of confusion later about which preference value went to which file.

Answer (score 1):

Create single singleton class which will handle ALL your preferences, ideally you should have a getter and setter for each preference and you will only do:

```
Preferences.getInstance().getSomePref();
```

and

```
Preferences.getInstance().setSomePref(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the same `SharedPreferences` for every call

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

It will be easy enough to build a wrapper helper class with `String get(String key)` and `void set(String key)` around that.

Something like

```
class MyPrefs {

  static MyPrefs instance;

  static synchronized getInstance(Context ctx) {
     if(instance == null) {
        instance = PreferenceManager.getDefaultharedPreferences(ctx);
     }
     return instance;

  }

  //then getters and setters e.g.
  int getInt(String key, int defVal) {
     return Integer.valueOf(getString(key))
  }

  String get(String key) {
    return instance.getString(key);
  }
}
```