# Android Sharedpreferences doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have problem with sharedpreferences, something goes wrong and I always get a default value.
My sharedpref class is:

```
public class IntolleranceData {

    static SharedPreferences intolleranceData;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor intolleranceEditor;

    static final String FISH_KEY="00000";
}
```

I save value in Activity by:

```
intolleranceData = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("intolleranceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();
intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something").apply();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fish: " + intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY, "error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and this is great (toast shows correct string -"fish: something") but if I try to use sharedpreferences in fragment (in the same Activity and SharedPreferences, Activity and Fragment are in the same package) by:

```
intolleranceData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("intolleranceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();

String myKey = intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"error");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fish: "+myKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It shows "fish: 00000" so this is default value...

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: No need to call edit() when you read data.. only getSharedPreferences() then your getString()

Comment: I know that intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit(); in fragment is useless but I only declare it and do nothing. I read data by intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"error"); but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking to make sure that your GetActivity() isn't null before you reference it to return the SharedPreferences.

Also, you are using 'apply()' to add your changes to the SharedPreferences, which is a process which runs in the background. If you try and read from the data too early (e.g. simultaneously) then you can often get the default value. Alternatively, use .commit() to save your changes to the SharedPreferences.

Finally, if the problem is unrelated to either of these common issues, saving 'getActivity().getApplicationContext()' to a variable when the fragment is initialized, it should help with the problem of the context not linking correctly!

Best of Luck!

Comment: I checked it and getActivity() doesn't return null

Comment: You are using 'apply()' to add your changes to the SharedPreferences, which is a process which runs in the background. If you try and read from the data too early (e.g. simultaneously) then you can often get the default value. Alternatively, use .commit() to save your changes to the SharedPreferences.

Comment: If your problem is not related to the speed of the update to SharedPreferences, I would recommend saving 'getActivity().getApplicationContext()' to a variable as the fragment is created, which should help you keep the context linked even when the fragment is detached.

Comment: Have you succeeded yet? I'm hoping you get this up and running perfectly as you would like it to!

Comment: code is not perfect but application works, when I put a few value into SharedPref only first was fine so I created one SharedPref object for one value

Answer (score 0):

There is need to change your file like this, In the Place of

```js
intolleranceData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("intolleranceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();

String myKey = intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"error");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fish: "+myKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You Must change Your code Like this, way,.... and also you just simply change your **getActivity()** with **className.this**

```js
intolleranceData = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("intolleranceData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();

String myKey = intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"error");
introlleranceEditor.commit();
introllerenceEditor.apply();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fish: "+myKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried but there is an error Error:(54, 40) error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity (in MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences)

Comment: you want to display data in fragment@barmi

Comment: There is need to implement **FragmentManager** and **FragmentContainer** in your activity

Comment: Try to change MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences in both main and sharedpreferedes

Comment: This is a little more complicated, I have MainActivity, there is container for fragment and fragment has another container but I am pretty sure that there is not problem, everything is displaying correct, just sharepref doesn't works

Comment: this is impossible to use it in fragment (MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences)

Comment: hoo, kk simply try this code with out giving **MainActivity.this**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need editor to read data.
When you send data use

```
intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something");
intolleranceEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Yes but first you have to send it and you're doing it wrong

Comment: Why wrong? Is there any difference between your code and intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something").commit(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You should commit after you add the string...

```
intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something");
intolleranceEditor.commit();
```

Comment: I used editor.putString(KEY,"str").commit; but tried your version too, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I got your Problem i will give you a Perfect answer for your problem simply check this code......

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static SharedPreferences intolleranceData;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor intolleranceEditor;
    static final String FISH_KEY="00000";
static final String File_Name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

intolleranceData = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("File_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myKey = intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fish: "+myKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
}
```

and in **Shared Preferece or Inside button Click you can write this code**

```js
intolleranceData = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("File_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();
intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something")
intolleranceEditor.commit();
intolleranceEditor.apply();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fish: " + intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY, "error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)..show();
```

If you Solve your problem give a simple response

Answer (score 0):

I understand that **you trying to use this code display a message in the Fragment** kk, try this code.....

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static SharedPreferences intolleranceData;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor intolleranceEditor;
    static final String FISH_KEY="00000";
static final String File_Name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

intolleranceData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("File_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myKey = intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY,"");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fish: "+myKey,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
}
```

and In Shared Prefereces

```js
intolleranceData = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("File_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
intolleranceEditor = intolleranceData.edit();
intolleranceEditor.putString(FISH_KEY, "something")
intolleranceEditor.commit();
intolleranceEditor.apply();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fish: " + intolleranceData.getString(FISH_KEY, "error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)..show();
```

Comment: getApplicationContext() works only in Activities, getActivities() works in fragment, your suggestion is not compiled

Comment: i totally confusing your question please will you possible post your total coding @barmi

Comment: Here is an example how to solve my problem, it works [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences