# Save firebase notification in text by sharedpreference

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Through this code I can display the notification in a text message, but I want to save the text message by by sharedpreference until another notification arrives to replace it even if the application is closed

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

    setTitle(title);
    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc1);
    desc.setText(message);



}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734721/android-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

      String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
      String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

      setTitle(title);
      TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc1);
      desc.setText(message);

      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PrefName", 
      MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
      editor.putString("message", message);
      editor.apply();  
  }
```

Comment: when I close app and open it again the text not saved